# ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

karma.config.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: ['--no-sandbox']
        }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

karma server is failing everytime I run it. How do i resolve this issue.
I tried to checked out the code freshly and ran npm install but still facing same issue.

**package.json**

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post code snippets instead of screeshots

Comment: code is not the issue. karma server itself is not starting